# Android Youtube API exit the Fullscreen when pressed the back button

Tags: android, youtube, fullscreen, onbackpressed

when the video is playing on the Fullscreen.i want pressed the back button can exit the Fullscreen,i have been try to **overrride** the **onbackPress** and **onKeydown**
but is not work.please help me

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    System.out.println("here");
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackeventlistener);
    youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(onFullscreenListener);
    you = youTubePlayer;

    if (b) {

         youTubePlayer.cueVideo(Video_id);

    }}


    youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
    youTubePlayer.setManageAudioFocus(false);
    youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);

}

  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (isFullscreen.equals(true)){
        you.setFullscreenControlFlags(0);
        isFullscreen = false;
        you.setFullscreen(false);


    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have tried same thing but after assigning youtubeplayer in global variable.
but on backbutton press I am geting player variable value always null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isFullscreen.equals(true)){
        isFullscreen = false;
        you.setFullscreen(false);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: @K.Rock May be isFullScreen flag is false. Can you check it?

Comment: I got it!!
delete "you.setFullscreenControlFlags(0);"

Comment: I have tried this but youtubeplayer gets released when back is pressed.